# web service in php is not displaying results

Tags: php, json, post

my php web service is not giving me json result from my database when i run it in web browser or i try to connect to it from my android app. When i test it through postman it gives me back results i json.
Here is my php code:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include 'connection.php';
    showStudent();
}

function showStudent()
{
    global $connect;

    $query = " Select * FROM demo; ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $temp_array  = array();

    if($number_of_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $temp_array[] = $row;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("demo"=>$temp_array));
    mysqli_close($connect);

}

?>
```

here is my result from database through postman:

[image]

whil in web browser im not getting any of this:
[image]

can anybody see any problem with this, im actually not a php developer i tried to wrote this on my own for a project.

Thanks

Comment: Did you call your showStudent.php with a POST request or did you just type it in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for the method of submission first which is `POST`. while when you hit direct url it work as `GET`. So for getting data in web change `POST` to `GET`.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"){
    include 'connection.php';
    showStudent();
}
```

Comment: its nice to hear that it work. You can accept my answer in that case.. :)